# Dynamic routing base on clicked bottoms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

please am stocked trying to create a way for an admin to preview a file before creating users from the file("an xls file"), the problem am faced with is not knowing how to dynamically change the route base on the button the admin clicked, the buttons are supposed to either go to preview the file or create the users from the file.

```
<%= form_for :create_student, url:"/create_from_file", remote:true, html:{id:"create_student_from_file"} do|f| %>
   <div id="student-fields0" class="fields_div">
      <%= f.label "Upload file"%>
      <%= f.file_field :Upload_file %>
      <%= f.submit :create, id: 'create_student' %>
      <div id="preview_student" class="button">preview</div>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You can check if current user is admin.

Comment: that's not the case @Daniel, i am trying to preview the file before creating the users, preview button is supposed to preview student details while create would create them. i wanted a case were when a button is clicked it would go to a given route in the controller.

Comment: Do you mean one button for 2 actions?

Comment: No i mean, two buttons for two different actions, it goes to a given action depending on what is been clicked @Daniel

Comment: If you want change url dynamically, you can use Javascript.

Comment: I would solve that in controller: `return redirect_to_preview(params) if params[:submit] == 'preview'`

Comment: Please @nattfodd 2 am not clear with your solution.

Comment: OK I would try doing that and get back to you @Daniel

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this that way, for example:

## Controller part

```
class YourContoller < ApplicationController
  # POST /create_from_file 
  def create_from_file
    # Initialize user or something
    user = User.new(params)

    if params[:preview]
      return redirect_to(:preview_from_file, user: user)
    end

    # Create new user here
  end

  # GET /preview_from_file
  # Add another view for preview page
  def preview_from_file
    @user = params[:user]
  end
end
```

## View part

```
<%= form_for :create_student, url:"/create_from_file", remote:true, html:{id:"create_student_from_file"} do|f| %>
   <div id="student-fields0" class="fields_div">
      <%= f.label "Upload file"%>
      <%= f.file_field :Upload_file %>
      <%= f.submit :create, id: 'create_student' %>
      // This is what changed compared to your current view
      <%= submit_tag 'preview', name: 'preview', value: 'true', class: 'button' %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```